# VM boots with wrong keyboard layout

Tags: centos, keyboard-layout, bios, vmware-workstation

***Question edited, please keep in mind when reading the comments below.***

I use VMware Workstation Player to run my Linux VMs.  Starting from the boot and during GRUB menu, LUKS password entry, and initial user login screen, the keyboard appears to be set to US.  This is source of errors when entering passwords as I have a French Swiss keyboard (QWERTZ).  The system uses the correct keyboard layout (CH-FR) only after the user has logged in.

How can I set the correct keyboard locale on a CentOS 8 Stream VM so that it is applied since the boot?

This is the output of `localectl`:

```
System Locale: LANG=en_US.UTF-8
    VC Keymap: ch-fr
   X11 Layout: us
    X11 Model: pc105+inet
  X11 Options: terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp
```

I found [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/974833/change-the-keyboard-layout-of-grub-in-stage-1) for Ubuntu, but it references a UEFI system.
My VM uses BIOS. Is there a way to do so that does not require UEFI?

Comment: `xmodkeymap` (I might be misremembering the name of the command) apparently only the X Server's key map :/ maybe there's an option in GRUB to specify it tho? as a boot parameter

Comment: I'm using azerty by putting `KEYMAP=fr` in `/etc/vconsole.conf`. I don't know which name has the qwertz layout, but you can check with `localectl list-keymaps` and put the name of that layout in that conf file I guess.

Comment: @Pierre-AlainTORET Hmmm, interesting. My `/etc/vconsole.conf` already contains `KEYMAP=ch-fr`.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read carefully enough. It looks like https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1777599 is your problem but console-setup is not shipped anymore for CentOS 8 it seems. I checked on https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/tree/PKGBUILD?h=ckbcomp and it seems that ckbcomp is just a shell script you can get from https://salsa.debian.org/installer-team/console-setup/-/raw/1.203/Keyboard/ckbcomp (latest release it seems) and put in /usr/bin and chmod it for execution. After that I was able to run grub2-kbdcomp as expected. Hope that helps.

Comment: For that last one you need to install `grub2-efi-x64-modules`. ` dnf provides /usr/lib/grub/x86_64-efi/modinfo.sh` helped me :)

Comment: Could you paste the output of `efibootmgr -v` please ? Also was `/boot/efi/EFI/centos/grubx64.efi` where the grubx64.efi used to be ?